# trying to datalayer update with set() build-in method but not updating

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

trying to update a value in my datalayer but I can't get it to work. See code below. This inside a class that has btn click methods. btw.

```
if (window.google_tag_manager["GTM-XXXXX"].dataLayer.get('ecommerce') !== undefined) {
      console.log('update')
      window.google_tag_manager["GTM-XXXXXX"].dataLayer.set('ecommerce', {
        'productId': `${this.product.id}`, 
        'productName': `${this.product.productName}`
      })
   
    } else {
      console.log('create')
      window.dataLayer.push({ 
        'ecommerce': {
          'productId': `${this.product.id}`, 
          'productName': `${this.product.productName}`
      }});
    }
```

According to this documentation, it should work. https://javascript.tutorialink.com/how-to-update-a-datalayer-variable/

The values get picked up upon click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need to `update the dataLayer`

You can just push it and it will update automatically if you use Google Tag Manager - DataLayer Variable to get the data.

Any specific use case or requirement?

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought, but it isn't doing it. I read that the datalayer will automatically find the object and update it. but it doesn't, it creates a new one.. not sure why..

Comment: Can you share about how you use the datalayer variable for now? I might need to see how you configure it on the Google Tag Manager